# Multiple Capture Group in REGEXP TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to use multiple capture group inside single regexp in TCL,

```
set var "      abc 123"
regexp -all "^(\s*)(\[a-z\]*)(\s*)(\[0-9\]*)" $var match1 match2 match3 match4
```

Please correct my regular expression and syntax if it is worng.

I want to get output like this,

```
puts $match1  ;# Contains multiple spaces
puts $match2  ;# Contains abc
puts $match3  ;# Contains single space
puts $match4  ;# Contains 123
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm) and the [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/986)? There are examples there which should make it easy to get the syntax right.

Comment: I have looked at it already. But in that there is example of single capture group. Not about multiple. Thanks..

Comment: That's not true. The wiki has this example `regexp {(some) (expression)} $item -> var1 var2`.

Comment: Ok... I have not used `->` inside TCL regexp that's why probably i ignored that part. Sorry.

Comment: @AxT_8041: Note that in that example the `->` is nothing special. It's just a variable. If you find it less confusing you may use `all_matches` instead of `->`. You can see that it's a variable because you can print its value: `puts [set "->"]` (note: you need to use `set` instead of `$` because the variable name `->` violates what's allowed for `$`)

Comment: The `-all` switch isn't helpful here. It's used together with `-inline` to get a list of repeated matches, or without `-inline` to fill the variables with the *last* set of matches in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
regexp -all {^(\s*)([a-z]*)(\s*)([0-9]*)}  $var whole_match match1 match2 match3 match4
```

Or,

```
regexp -all "^(\\s*)(\[a-z]*)(\\s*)(\[0-9]*)"  $var whole_match match1 match2 match3 match4
```

Braces will take the literal meaning of characters, but not for double quotes. So, backslashes and square brackets are escaped in them. We don't need to escape the closing square bracket.